# Получить значение ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста,
есть ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="professions" MouseDoubleClick="professions_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="val" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

и есть обработчик события:

```
private void professions_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        groupSostav.Items.Add("???");
    }
```

При двойном клике нужно чтобы вот этот (Text="{Binding Value}") value добавлялся в ListBox groupsostav, не получается его получить, что нужно подставить в (groupSostav.Items.Add("???");) вместо "???" ?

В ListBox записи добавлены из конструктора вот так :

```
Dictionary<int, string> col1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {1, "Значение 1"},
            {2, "Значение 2"},
            {3, "Значение 3"}
        };
        foreach (var profList in col1)
        {
            professions.Items.Add(new Item { Key = profList.Key, Value = profList.Value });
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Как-то странно вы работаете: вроде бы байдинг применять пытаетесь и в тоже время в кодбихайде на событиях заполняете списки. Вы уж определитесь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь работать с байдингом, то вот вам пример на ваш случай, но без работы в MVVM, как это обычно принято.

**XAML**

```
<Canvas>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForListView}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInListView}"
              Height="100" Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="33" 
              Width="215" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="н/п"
                                Width="30"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Название"
                                Width="150"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForListBox}"
         Height="180" Canvas.Left="323" Canvas.Top="40" Width="125">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Canvas>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция для ListView
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsForListView { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Элемент выбранный в ListView
    /// </summary>
    private Item _SelectedItemInListView;
    public Item SelectedItemInListView
    {
        get { return _SelectedItemInListView; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItemInListView = value;
            //сообщаем о том, что элемент изменился
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemInListView)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция для ListBox
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsForListBox { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //подписываемся на событие загрузки окна
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие загрузки окна
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadLists();

        //делаем кодбихайнд источником данных для своего XAML
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заполнение списков
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadLists()
    {
        ItemsForListView = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item() { Key = 1, Value = "Значение 1"},
            new Item() { Key = 2, Value = "Значение 2"},
            new Item() { Key = 3, Value = "Значение 3"}
        };

        ItemsForListBox = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события двойного клика мышью на ListView
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedItemInListView != null)
        {
            ItemsForListBox.Add(SelectedItemInListView);
        }
    }
}

    public class Item
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался, а как можно вывести индекс элемента коллекции ItemsForListBox?

Comment: @Дмитрий решение "в лоб" создать еще одно свойство типа `int` назвать его как-нибудь "SelectedIndexInListBox" и привязать его в ListBox `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexInListBox}"`, да, и не забудьте в этом свойстве реализовать у `set` оповещение об изменении с пом. `PropertyChanged(this,...)`, смотрите как это было сделано у свойства `SelectedItemInListView`

Comment: @Дмитрий потом с этим свойством "SelectedIndexInListBox"  можно делать что хотите, вывести наружу -  создайте `TextBlock` и привяжите `Text="{Binding SelectedIndexInListBox}"`

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так:

```
private int _SelectedIndexInListBox;
    public int SelectedIndexInListBox
    {
        get { return _SelectedIndexInListBox; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedIndexInListBox = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedIndexInListBox)));
        }
    }
```

И вывод:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="№"DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedIndexInListBox}">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedIndexInListBox}"></TextBlock>
     </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Ничего не выводит, а если создаю отдельный ТекстБокс (за пределами ListView), то когда тыкаю мышкой по элементам ListView к которому привязан, значение выводится (индекс того элемента который я выбрал).

Два варианта вывода сделал потому что тестил, не работает ни 1 из вариантов :(